# How to check the default port number for mysql connection? Connection not working! jdbc connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connection

I am trying to connect with database using jdbc in java file. It is not connecting at all and giving me the error constantly "Something went wrong"; I guess it is because of the port number because all other data such as username, password and other code seems correct.

I want to check the default port number so that I can try it properly. I did try using all three of these 8080, 80 and 3306 but it shows me error.

Here port 8080 is used for HTTP server, 3306 is supposed to be default from the research and 80 randomly.

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver found");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver not found");
    }

    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080 or 80 or 3306 or without port number/test";
    String user="user";
    String password="";

    Connection con=null;

    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println("Success");
    } catch (SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error is giving below when used String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

```
  Driver found
  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not     received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at com.town.connect.Dbconnection.main(Dbconnection.java:26)
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
... 15 more
```

Comment: Port 8080 is the Tomcat port. It is vanishingly unlikely that MySQL will be using that port. The usual MySQL port is 3306, which is what you will get if you omit it from the URL altogether. NB the Class.forName() line hasn't been needed for seven years.

Comment: What is the error thrown when `'3306'` port was used?

Comment: My TomcT port is 8080 however PHPmyadmin port is 3306 so which one should be used for the connection?

Comment: Use `'e.printStacktrace()'` instead of `'sop("something went wrong")'`. Post the same error stack in your question.

Comment: @SandeshRana I've just answered that.

Comment: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
This is the error

Comment: No. Post the stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Comment: @EJP, please check the error

Comment: The underlying error that you've been doing your best to obscure is 'connection refused'. That means you got either the IP address or the port number wrong in the connection URL. Nothing more. Is the MySQL server really running?

Comment: @EJP, I am using PHPmyadmin for SQL and XAMPP control to run the MYSQL. Yes it is working properly where mysql is using 3306 port number.

Comment: So your question is answered? Contrary to your claim under @sol4me's answer? NB Neither PHPMyAdmin nor XAMPP has anything to do with this question.

Comment: @EJP, I finally found the solution. After all the research, I commented out skip-networking in my.cnf and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access those settings via

```
mysql> show variables;
```

Comment: Thanks nice and easy. I found out that it has been using 3306 port number but I did try using this port number but then it is still showing me the error. Any idea where I have made mistake?

Comment: @SandeshRana are you using java 7?

Comment: @SandeshRana It is still showing you ***what*** error? You haven't provided an error message in your question or comments. Other than your own stupid error message, of course. The exception's own message is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbaddress+"/"+dbname+"?user=" + username + "&password=" + password)
```

This statement can help you. No need to define any other port. Just define the following variables as per your mysql configuration.

- dbaddress
- dbname
- username
- password

And if this doesn't works can you post the stacktrace or a screenshot for your error ?

Comment: It isn't clear that he doesn't need to define a port. There's not enough information provided in the question to determine that.

Comment: I agree to your point @EJP. But its worth giving a try. I have requested for a screenshot or stacktrace if that doesn't works. To provide a solution to this problem, more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the port number you can use following command

SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';